# mysql left join with count from right table including zero

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables as `complaints` and `attachments`

I want to list all complaints along with their attachment count (just counts). If no records found from right table (`attachments`) then 0 as attachment count.

I'm using this query,

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(COUNT(p.pic_id), 0) FROM complaints c 
LEFT JOIN attachments p 
ON c.compl_id = p.compl_id 
ORDER BY comp_date DESC
```

But It just returns that rows which are present in right table (`attachments` table). I just want to list all rows from `complaints` table along with respective attachment count (If not count then 0).

Tables :

```
complaints
============
compl_id
cust_id
cust_msg
comp_date

attachments
============
pic_id
compl_id
```

**EDIT:**

```
complaints
===============
comp1   cust1   abcd    1/1/2015
comp2   cust5   hey     1/1/2015
comp3   cust60  hello   1/1/2015

attachments
===============
a_34554sdfs     comp2
1_idgfdfg34     comp2
```

I want to have results like this,

```
comp1   cust1   abcd    1/1/2015    0
comp2   cust5   hey     1/1/2015    2
comp3   cust60  hello   1/1/2015    0
```

But currently, I am getting result like this,

```
comp2   cust5   hey     1/1/2015    2
```

Comment: Aggregate function without `group by` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm new at Joins. I have searched a lot but can't get it worked.

Comment: In that case you need to provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Why is comp3 not in results (hoping this is just an oversight)?  comp1 has no attachment either but yet it's there...

Comment: @xQbert. Sorry to confuse you. I just forgot `cop3` in example. That just I want to do. If no attachment, get it as 0.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need a group by to get the desired results.  MySQL extends aggregate functions to not require a group by.  However, unless you know how to leverage this functionality, you'll likely get the wrong results most of the time.  The only time to really use it is when all values in the column are the same; which I doubt is the case here.

```
SELECT compl_ID, cust_ID, cust_msg, comp_date, coalesce(count(Pic_ID),0) as Attach_Count
FROM complaints C
LEFT JOIN attachments A
 on C.compl_ID = A.Compl_ID
GROUP BY compl_ID, cust_ID, cust_msg, comp_date
```

Comment: `GROUP BY compl_id` helped to get it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can't I just use `GROUP BY compl_id` safely instead of `GROUP BY compl_ID, cust_ID, cust_msg, comp_date`. PS : The compl_id in the complaints table is primary key.

Comment: [The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)  So, you're willing to accept indeterminate values for the other columns you really need to group by each of them.  So yes syntactically you can, but you'll get indeterminate results if the values in a column vary; which based on your case they would... so while you can do it... you shouldn't unless you want wrong values in some of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, removing the IFNULL:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(p.pic_id)
FROM complaints c
LEFT JOIN attachments p
ON c.compl_id = p.compl_id 
ORDER BY comp_date DESC
```

Comment: Since the author is using aggregate function "COUNT", the "GROUP BY" statement should be added to query.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(c.compl_id) AS count
FROM complaints c
INNER JOIN attachments a USING(compl_id)
GROUP BY c.compl_id;
```